# Javascript call grails domain with specific query and condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grails

I am new to grails and react. In my grails proj, I have GORM as below table view.

```
class Lot {

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    //match RTD rules
    String area
    String stepName
    String stepGroup
    String totalLotWaiting
```

and the data and table view is as below picture,

[Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCEod.png)

What I wanted to do is, I want to call from javascript the total_lot_waiting value by any of 3 column (area, step_name or step_group). I only want one value to be returned(total lot waiting). As you see, for example even we have many area 'WT' but the total lot waiting value will be always same for all duplicate WT areas. So when I request by any of that first 3 column value, it should return me only one total waiting value.

In javascript there is a button declared as below, and I wanted to show the result in this button.

```
<Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large"
        style={{
          fontSize: '30pt',
          height: '75pt',
          width: '260pt',
          margin: '10pt'}}
        key={'select-' + area}
        active={active}
        data-dismiss="modal"
        onClick={() => handleAreaButtonClick(area)}>
        {area} **VALUE-HERE**
</Button>);
```

So in Javascript, i call the lot values by

```
 const lot = this.props.lot;
```

but then I don't know how I can do looping or is there any specific built in way in grails or react that I can call total lot waiting value by passing the area value. Something like

```
function TotalWaitingLot(area){
//code here to call the total waiting lot
return result
}
```

Appreciate any advice or suggestion on how I can further move on. Thanks

Comment: Can you describe what "total_lot_waiting value by any of 3 column (area, step_name or step_group)" means?

Comment: @JamesKleeh That mean when I query for any of this column area, step_name or step_group, the function in javascript should query and find its total_lot_waiting value and return it.